# Reference Error - angular not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

the following is my app.html - template where i will be injecting my other partial views as to come,

```
<html ng-app="billApp">
<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <!-- load angular via CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

...

<!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
<div id="main">
    {{ message }}

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the script.js file which is the controller for the application,

// script.js

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var billApp = angular.module('billApp', []);

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
billApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see!';
});
```

while i try to run the script.js file using my commandline

1. change directory to nodejs directory
2. type in *'node path-of-the-project-file\script.js'*

which throws the following error, 
 var billApp = angular.module('billApp', []);
 Reference error angular not defined.

I m somehow missing out on some basic detail. It would be great if someone could give me some directions here

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in your code. Please find the working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/zQ7PIgaJlwkPVCHeNIR2?p=preview

Comment: include jquery before angular

Comment: Thanks @varit05 it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>`

line with

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>`

Because its not getting library which is required by `ngResource`.

AND

Include this line in the beggining

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to incude jquery before the angular script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```